# Overflow when evaluating binomial coefficient

Tags: numerical-methods, binomial-coefficients, programming

I am struggling with overflow in my code and want to find a simple modification in such a way that overflow is minimized when trying to evaluate binomial coefficient for large n- and k values close to each other.

code:

```
def binomial_float(n, i):
    p = 1; q = 1
    for k in range(1, i+1):
       p *= (n-k+1)/k #could I modify something here for instance?
    return p

print(binomial_float(100000, 99940))
"""
Output:
inf #overflow
"""
```

Comment: I believe [this[0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a more appropriate site to ask your question.

Comment: Use symmetry binom(n,i)=binom(n,n-i) to reduce number of operations. // Could you please also document the test cases where you observed the overflow? Do you have a large n and small i or is the worst case i=n/2 always possible? // Sometimes it helps to accumulate products and quotients as sums and differences of the logarithms, using an exponential for the final result.

Comment: i want to modify code given that i > n/2

Comment: insert at the start `if 2*i>n: return binomial_float(n,n-i)`

Comment: Really clever. Thank you so much.